# Convert OpenSSH ED25519 Private Key Format to PEM format

Tags: private-key, openssh, pem, ed25519

I have generated a an ED25519 SSH key pair using

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
```

The output of the `id_ed25519` file is in OpenSSH format:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I would like to convert it to a PEM file format. If it were an RSA key pair, there would be no need for that as an RSA `id_rsa` key is already in a PEM file format but the ED25519 key pair is an OpenSSH format.

How can I convert this to a PEM file format?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: Nothing worked for me, so I ended up generating from scratch with OpenSSL: `openssl genpkey -algorithm ed25519 -out private.pem && openssl pkey -in private.pem -pubout -out public.pem`

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
ssh-keygen -p -f path/to/your/key -m pem
```

to convert your key file to PEM, but be sure to make a backup of the file first.

Taking from https://github.com/pickware/github-action-ssh-agent

Comment: The `-m pem` option also works to generate a new SSH ed25519 key with PEM encoding; `ssh-keygen -a 64 -t ed25519 -m pem -f youykeyname`.  From the man page: `Setting a format of “PEM” when generating or updating a supported private key type will cause the key to be stored in the legacy PEM private key format.`

Comment: Did you check that this solution actually works? If yes, then what version of `ssh-keygen` were you using? For me, the version from OpenSSH 7.9p1 did not change the key format, but passphrase only.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov The Solution worked, but I dont know the version. Default Library from Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: According to @Gordon Davidson (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/143114/what-is-the-difference-between-pem-format-to-dsa-rsa-ecc-might-i-confuse-pem-w) older software won't understand the new format and some new types of content (Ed25519 keys) can only be stored in the new format.

Comment: with a common setup that includes setting file permissions this ends up in `Saving key "path/to/your/key" failed: Permission denied.`

Comment: -e option direct the output to the console instead of overwriting the key file

Comment: @MountainX+ both of those don't work; `-m pem` is accepted on either a set-password or generate command but for ed25519 it is ignored and the (re)written file is actually new-format, because there does not exist a 'PEM' format (i.e. OpenSSL legacy) for ed25519. (There _is_ a PKCS8 format for ed25519, but OpenSSH can't write it, although OpenSSL 9.6 two months ago can _read_ it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Puttygen to convert your ppk to pem.

The steps are these.

1. Importing your ppk private key to Puttygen
2. Choose RSA as the type of key to generate
3. Choose Conversions Menu > Export OpenSSH Key > Save
4. Use the saved file for your ssh tunnel identity file

Answer (score -3):

I think this would work:

```
openssl pkey -in ed25519.pem -out ed25519.pub -pubout
```

It does for a private key generated this way:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm ed25519 > ed25519.pem
```

I haven't tested ssh-keygen's private key format explicitly but I would assume that it is using OpenSSL under the hood. If the private key's base64 starts with "MC", then I would say it probably would be compatible.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP appears to be looking for a way to convert an ed25519 ssh key to the pem format. Most ssh keys are PEM by default iirc, but not ed25519 ssh keys.

Comment: @nrdxp: since OpenSSH 7.8 in 2018-08 the default is 'new format' (BEGIN/END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY) for all keytypes; before that the default was 'PEM' (really OpenSSL legacy) for keytypes other than ed25519. Both new format and ed25519 existed only since OpenSSH 6.5 in 2014-01.